# "Insight into whether" vs "insight as to whether"

Tags: word-usage

I've seen the expressions *insight into whether* and *insight as to whether* used. Are both correct? If so is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

This is really an idiomatic choice of preposition, so [a quick look into Google NGrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=insight+into%2Cinsight+as+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=1&smoothing=3) shows that "insight into" is by far the more used phrase.

EDIT: After thinking about it a bit more and since just posting an NGram unqualified seems like kind of bad form, there's [another question on this very StackExchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15667/to-gain-insight-into-or-on) that seems to come to the same conclusion, as well as various English sites offering [insight into correct preposition use.](http://www.iolani.honolulu.hi.us/Keables/KeablesGuide/PartThree/effective.htm)

Answer (score 1):

*Insight into whether* is quite common, as is *insight on* when no comparison is being made.  *Insight* itself implies intuition, and *as to* implies that you are dealing in absolutes, so I don't think it fits as well.

Related question:  [To gain insight into or on?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15667/to-gain-insight-into-or-on)