# "Better insight on my experience"?

Tags: prepositions

> Please take a look at my resume to have a *better insight on my* experience.

From my point of view, it looks correct, but because I have never seen anything like this before, I have some doubts.

Comment: Related:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15667/to-gain-insight-into-or-on

Answer (score 0):

Use `into` with `insight`. As far as I know 'into' is the correct preposition to be used with 'insight'.

Change the sentence to

> Please take a look at my resume to have a better insight into my
>   experience.

or

> For a better insight into my experience, please take a look at my
>   resume.